# Is there always another non-trivial hermitian matrix $A$ for $B$ that $e^{iAx_0} = e^{iBx_1}$, $x_0 \neq x_1$ being real numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are hermitian $n \times n$ matrix, with $A \neq B$. $x_0$ and $x_1$ are real numbers, with $x_0 \neq x_1$.

Let $B$ a given matrix, and $x_0$, $x_1$ are given numbers as well, with $x_0 \neq x_1$. Would there always be some $A$ such that $e^{iAx_0} = e^{iBx_1}$ that is not simply $Bx_1/x_0$?

What would happen if $n$ goes to infinity?

edit:
What if I also constrain $A$ to be so that $A \neq Bx_1/x_0 + 2\pi k/x_0$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is equivalent to $e^{iA} = e^{iBt}$ where $t = x_1/x_0$.

Since the exponential map is a group homomorphism, the preimage is the set of matrices of the form $Bt + X$ where $e^{iX} = 1$, i.e. $X$ is in the kernel. The kernel includes diagonal matrices with entries of the form $2\pi n$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$ which are Hermitian.

Comment: What? I'm pretty sure the $i$ out front makes that not work. Like, the diagonal matrix with $2\pi$ on the diagonal is Hermitian and in the kernel of $e^{iX}$.

Comment: Thanks that’s better

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=(Bx_1+2\pi k)/x_0$ (which is Hermitian), for any $k\in\Bbb{Z}$. Then
$$e^{iAx_0}=e^{i(Bx_1+2\pi k)}=e^{iBx_1+2\pi i}=e^{iBx_1},$$
so as long as $x_0\ne 0$, then the answer is yes, you can always find $A\ne B$ with the property you want.

Also you lost the $i$ in the equation in the body, but its there in the title, so I assume I'm answering the right question.